# Array Unexpected Multi Assignment

Tags: ruby

I have the following array:

```
@master = Array.new(4, Array.new(2, Array.new()))
=> [[[], []], [[], []], [[], []], [[], []]]
```

I'm attempting to assign the very first most value with:

```
@master[0][0] = "x"
=> "x"
```

But this is doing a multi assignment

```
@master
=> [["x", []], ["x", []], ["x", []], ["x", []]]
```

How do I assign only the first value? I'm hoping to get the following Array:

```
@master
=> [["x", []], [[], []], [[], []], [[], []]]
```

Comment: Two small Ruby points: 1.it is customary to omit parentheses when invoking a method that does not pass an argument (`m` rather than `m()`); and 2. `Array.new` (no arguments or block) is generally written `[]`.

Comment: As a general comment, I suggest you not be in such a rush to select an answer. You don’t want to discourage other answers and may wish to give readers still working on answers time to finish before awarding the greenie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that way you use the same reference for every sub array. Try this way

```
@master = Array.new(4) { Array.new(2) { Array.new } }
```

Comment: This worked -- I'll accept after 8 minutes. If I would have carefully read the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new) I guess I could have figured this out. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure Sir

Answer (score 3):

You are creating one array an assigning it to every element of the first array; try running this code:

```
@master.each { |e| puts e.object_id }
```

Output (your ids will be different):

```
70192803217260
70192803217260
70192803217260
70192803217260
```

As you can see, is the exact same object, so try using `@master = Array.new(4) { Array.new(2) { Array.new() } }` instead, which will create a new array for each item in the first array.